# Coded UI: how can i improve my code without hard coding?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I wrote custom click method which uses mouse click and clickcenter methods. I rarely calls 'ClickCenter' method so i used the hard coded value as in the script below and code works fine but want to avoid hard coding. Any help?

```
public void Click<T>(UITestControl window, params string[] propertyvalues) where T : HtmlControl
        {
            HtmlControl genericControl = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { window });            
            if (propertyvalues.Length == 2)
            {
                genericControl.SearchProperties.Add(propertyvalues);
                if (propertyvalues[1] == "Account Status...")
                {

                    ClickCenter(genericControl);
                    return;
                }               

            }
            else
                for (int i = 0; i < propertyvalues.Length; i = i + 2)
                {
                    genericControl.SearchProperties.Add(propertyvalues[i], propertyvalues[i + 1]);
                }            

            Mouse.Click(genericControl);

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hard coding"? You question is not at all clear about what you want to achieve. Please read [mcve] and then improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `BoundingRectangle` property of `UITestControl`. You don't need to pass the control to `Mouse.Click();` You can just pass absolute coordinates of control's center point, which you can calculate from `BoundingRectangle`:

> public static Point Center(this Rectangle rectangle) {
>   return new Point(rectangle.Left + rectangle.Width / 2, rectangle.Top + rectangle.Height / 2);
>           }